# SwiftUI - ScrollView scroll "steps"

Tags: swiftui, scrollview

New to SwiftUI.
I have a ScrollView and want to set some scrolling "steps".

For example: If the user scrolls the screen I want the ScrollView to scroll 500 pixels down. If scrolled again it should scroll down to another 500 pixels.

The scroll should be animated and not instant.
I searched the web for a solution but didn't find anything.

I don't want to scroll to a specific position, just down 500 pixels each time.

Comment: Sounds like you might not want `ScrollView`. Sounds like you just want a `VStack` that you can detect a gesture on and then offset the position a certain amount each time you detect the gesture.

Comment: Isn't really there a way to set a "scroll amount" for a ScrollView?

Comment: No -- a `ScrollView` follows the touch of the user. There is a concept of pagination for it, where it will snap to a page, which might be what you're looking for: https://www.hackingwithswift.com/quick-start/swiftui/how-to-make-a-scrollview-snap-with-paging-or-between-child-views

Comment: jnpdx, you're a lifesaver! Maybe I was after the wrong keywords in my research...

Answer (score 0):

If you ask for pagination for the whole screen, **TabView** helps you

```
ZStack {
    Color.red.ignoresSafeArea()

    TabView {
        TabPageView1()
        TabPageView2()
        TabPageView3()
    }
    .tabViewStyle(.page)
}
```

You can also make it dynamic with **ForEach**

```
ZStack {
    Color.red.ignoresSafeArea()

    TabView(selection: $currentTab) {
        ForEach(0 ..< maxPageCount, id: \.self) { index in
            TabPageView()
        }
    }
    .tabViewStyle(.page)
}
```

BTW, It works only horizontally.

Comment: Thanks, Yusuf but no, I was not asking for TabView pagination. What I was looking for is explained in the link posted by jnpdx in a previous comment.